# Echoing Object Data and Displaying In Dropdown

Tags: php

I am attempting to echo the character_name of the current user. How to get this is with the use of taking the default_character_id and running through the list of characters and getting the name of that character. Then below that display a dropdown menu with the rest of other characters that are inside of the characters property.

Any ideas on how this should be accomplished?

```
object(stdClass)#26 (18) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(5) "10004"
  ["role_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["default_character_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["characters"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#30 (6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["character_name"]=>
      string(5) "twilliams"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(5) "10004"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#31 (6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["character_name"]=>
      string(4) "ksmith"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#32 (6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["character_name"]=>
      string(11) "tjones"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
}

<a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="glyphicons cogwheel">
    <i></i>
    <?php
    //echo character name of logged in user
    ?>
    <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a href="">Some option</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Some other option</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Other option</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="glyphicons cogwheel">
    <i></i>
    <?php
      echo $object->characters[$object->default_character_id]->charachter_name;
    ?>
    <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a href="">Some option</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Some other option</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Other option</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's going to display the id though I'm looking to display the name as stated in my post.

Comment: That gives me:

    Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Any additional thoughts?

Comment: rather than copy and paste and expect it to work.. any chance you change the variable name to match yours? Im sure `$object` isn't the right variable name :-)

Comment: also I would go with `echo $object->characters[$object->default_character_id]->character_name;` seeing as the overall is an object in an array in an object..